# How can I reduce Try and Except statements in error-handling code

Tags: python, excel, error-handling

Working on a project that updates a database. New values (Rows) are updated from a folder containing Excel files. The values in the Excel files are provided by employees. Sometimes these employees are still working in the Excel file while trying to update the database. This results in  a PermissionError.

To avoid PermissionErrors, I use the Try and Except statement. This works fine but situations can occur that Excel files are not closed for a while and multiple Excel files are opened during the day.

Thus, just one Try and Except statement wouldn't work. Therefore I used three Try and and Except statements which still doesn't guarantee that errors are handled properly.

To solve this, I think a While loop or a break statement within the for loop would work? Tried to add a break statement at the end of the (first) except block but this didn't work..

Is there any way to tackle this? Adding more Try and Except statements would work, but that just seems silly.

```
if update_number_files == 0:
    print("No new files to update")
elif update_number_files >= 1:
    print("Update error")
else:
    print(str(abs(update_number_files)) + " files will be updated")
    for file in selected_update_files:
        try:
            dfs = pd.read_excel(file, "Sheet2")
        except PermissionError:
            print("PermissionError")
            time.sleep(300)
            try:
                dfs = pd.read_excel(file, "Sheet2")
            except PermissionError:
                print("PermissionError")
                time.sleep(300)
                try:
                    dfs = pd.read_excel(file, "Sheet2")
                except PermissionError:
                    print("PermissionError")
                    time.sleep(300)
                    dfs = pd.read_excel(file, "Sheet2")
        New_file.append(dfs)
        join = pd.concat(New_file)
```

Comment: Your proposed `while` loop approach should work, however, you mentioned employees and this whole proposition seems way too fragile to use in the real world, i.e. I wouldn't want my paycheck depending on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly iterative code, not cascaded dependencies.  Yes, *use a loop*.

```
max_attempt = 3

for file in selected_update_files:
    dfs = None
    for attempt in range(max_attempt):
        try:
            dfs = pd.read_excel(file, "Sheet2")
        except PermissionError:
            print("PermissionError on read attempt", attempt)
            time.sleep(300)

    if not dfs:
        print("Failed to read", file)
```

Will that handle your problem?

Comment: I think the loops should be ordered the other way around to match the original code intent.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel [insert head-slap].  I'm coding inside-out again.  Thanks.

Comment: @Prune Thanks! Changed last piece of code to: if dfs is None. Now i can pay my employees ;)

Comment: Yup -- `not dfs` and `dfs is None` should be equivalent for you, but `is None` is safer in case of a "falsy" data frame result.

Comment: Oh ... remember to accept the answer so the question gets archived properly.  Upvote is appreciated, but cleaning up the question life cycle is more important.